# Is this behavior intended in C or is it platform dependent?

Tags: c

I remembered the fast inverse square root algorithm from quake 3 and wanted to do some bit shenanigans.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int x[2] = {0xffffffff, 0x0f01};
    
    unsigned long y = * (long *) &x[0];
    
    unsigned long z = ((unsigned long)x[1] << 32) + x[0];
    
    printf("x[0] = %x, x[1] = %x\n(x[1] << 32) + x[0] = %lx\ny = %lx", x[0], x[1], z, y);

    return 0;
}
```

and it outputs this

```
x[0] = ffffffff, x[1] = f01
(x[1] << 32) + x[0] = f01ffffffff
y = f01ffffffff
```

Is it supposed to be doing this?

Comment: What surprises you about the program's output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this behavior intended in C or is it platform dependent?

Technically, it's undefined behavior. You are accessing a variable of type `unsinged int` dereferencing a `long` pointer. [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule). And really, it's on wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root#Avoiding_undefined_behavior .

```
unsigned int x[2];    
*(long *) &x[0]; // invalid
```

If it's not undefined behavior and your compiler is trying to make sense of it, then you need to be lucky so that `&x[0]` is *aligned* to `alingof(long)`. If you are lucky and your compiler is trying to make sense of it and the stars are in the right positions, then the result depends on endianess. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness . I.e. you get `0xf01ffffffff` on x86 and `0xffffffff00000f01` on ARM.

Comment: So it is undefined and platform dependent, neat

Answer (score 1):

By dereferencing the address `&x[0]` and treating the object located at that address as a `long`, although it is an `unsigned int`, you are violating the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule), which causes [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

> Is it supposed to be doing this?

It can do anything it wants, as the behavior of your program is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

It is perhaps interesting to consider a similar program whose behavior is well-defined (aliasing via a union is permitted in C), but still may differ between platforms:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void) {
    union {
        uint32_t x[2];
        uint64_t y;
    } u = { {0xffffffff, 0x0f01} };
    
    uint64_t z = ((uint64_t)u.x[1] << 32) + u.x[0];
    
    printf("x[0] = %" PRIx32 ", x[1] = %" PRIx32 "\n(x[1] << 32) + x[0] = %" PRIx64 "\ny = %" PRIx64 "\n",
            u.x[0], u.x[1], z, u.y);

    return 0;
}
```

It happens to produce the same output for me on my machine as your program did for you:

> $ ./a.out
> x[0] = ffffffff, x[1] = f01
> (x[1] << 32) + x[0] = f01ffffffff
> y = f01ffffffff

Among other things, this shows that on my machine (as, probably, on yours) both 32-bit and 64-bit unsigned integers are represented with little-endian byte order.